# Windows Task Scheduler - Inputting SSO User/PW, then executing additoinal tasks

Tags: windows-7, task-scheduler

I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise and am trying to have Task Scheduler type a username and password for me.

My ultimate goal is to have TS open a web page, which I was able to do, then put in User/PW and Enter, wait a few seconds, then execute another Task that opens up other programs that require that first SSO (Single Sign-On).

Please inform me if/how this can be done.

Thank you for your assistance,
Jason.

Comment: so is your question how to make one task fire as the result of another task ending? That can be done, but the few seconds delay will have to be written into the second task's script/executable. you make the trigger of the second task fire "On Event" and indicate the event log and event id for the logged message indicating that the first task has completed.

Comment: Thank you! The main purpose of my inquiry is to make TS open a browser AND automatically follow these steps: Type in username-tab-type in password-enter. Then a few seconds later, execute the next task I've made. I hard part for me is getting TS to input the user/PW fields.